# Need to use cut command for the below file

Tags: bash

```
ff_rms_mark_head_gp_20221019569987.dat.gz
ff_rms_sharp_head_20221019569987_full.dat.gz
```

Here there are two types of file. One is `full` and one more is `gp`, these are the differences. However, in this case I need to use cut command to get below details

....

Output:
``
Table_Name should be: "mark_head for first file

for second table should be "sharp_head"

"Differences between two tables are "gp" and "full" ". table name may decrease or increase

Date: 2022-10-19

````
`Table Name` would start from `rms_` till `gp` but if there is no `gp` then till `date`)

The date would be with the following format:

```python
date=2022-10-19
````

Comment: Are your files (`*.gz`) on the filesystem? Or are they examples of strings inside a file?

Comment: .gz file as mentioned above

Comment: Where do you want to save the details? In the terminal? or in a file, or a variable, etc.? Specify it in your question

Comment: in a variable as Table_name and Date

Comment: What about `mark_head` and `sharp_head`, should they be assigned to a variable too?

Comment: there are two types of files above. one is mark_head_gp and another one is witout gp(sharp_head)gp is constant

Comment: Hence I should get first file name as mark_head and second file name should be sharp_head

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ output you are expecting. I am afraid it is very hard to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Make sure you are placed in the directory where you have ***.gz files** before running this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.gz; do
   
   echo -e "=========================================="
   echo Current file "$file"

   fhead=$(cut -d '_' -f3,4 <<< "$file")
   sixthCol=$(cut -d '_' -f6 <<< "$file")

   if [[ ${sixthCol%%.*} = "full" ]];then
      #Table name till date
      fdate=$(cut -d '_' -f5 <<< "$file" | awk -v FS='' -v OFS='-' '{print $1$2$3$4,$5$6,$7$8}')
      tableName="$(cut -d '_' -f2-4 <<< "$file")_${fdate}"
   else
      #Table name till gp
      fdate=$(cut -d '_' -f6 <<< "$file" | awk -v FS='' -v OFS='-' '{print $1$2$3$4,$5$6,$7$8}')
      tableName=$(cut -d '_' -f2-5 <<< "$file")
   fi

   echo Table_Name: $tableName
   echo Head: $fhead
   echo Date: $fdate
   echo -e "==========================================\n\n"
done
```

Assuming that you have these files:

```
ff_rms_mark_head_gp_20221019569987.dat.gz
ff_rms_sharp_head_20221019569987_full.dat.gz
```

If you run the script above you will get the following output:

```
==========================================
Current file ./ff_rms_mark_head_gp_20221019569987.dat.gz
Table_Name: rms_mark_head_gp
Head: mark_head
Date: 2022-10-19
==========================================


==========================================
Current file ./ff_rms_sharp_head_20221019569987_full.dat.gz
Table_Name: rms_sharp_head_2022-10-19
Head: sharp_head
Date: 2022-10-19
==========================================
```

The `Head` might not be important (and the `Date`, perhaps). If you want any other specific output then you should provide a detailed information about what you really want.
About the script, it will work for any number of *.gz files* (either `gp` or `full`).

Comment: its working fine however the table name will may change like (mark_head_store, mark_head_country_base, coutry_sale_performance_invent)

Comment: @Giri as terdon said you should edit your question and provide your  expected output. With your comment it seems that what you want it's more complex than what I understand.